# Quick scroll icon in cordova app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Is there a corodva plugin that adds support for Quick scroll icon like google Photos has?

[image]

Comment: That is a UI feature. You likely can add that from your UI framework, if you are using one.